# Access - Best way to return employee list based on another table

Tags: ms-access

Hopefully I can explain this in a way that someone will understand what I am trying to achieve and be able to offer a possible solution.

I am creating a database for managing Health and Safety at my workplace. I have one table created to store employees - "Table: Employees". This table has the usual fields (First Name, Last Name etc.) but specifically has the following fields: "Departments" (Multiple selection as employees can move between), "Additional Competencies" (e.g. Forklift, Order Picker etc. (Again multiple selection)), and "Gender".

I have a second table ("Table: Toolbox Talks") which is where the system stores tool box talks (created by the user through a form. "Form: Toolbox Talk"). The intended recipients of a toolbox talk will generally be limited to either one or more departments, or maybe just all forklift drivers or all of one gender. When the user creates a new toolbox talk (record), they will in the form (Form: Toolbox Talk) select from drop down lists the appropriate variables (Department, Competency, Gender). (N.B. a toolbox talk can sometimes be relevant to more than just one.)

What I am trying to achieve is to some how create a query that for each toolbox talk, it will return only the employees who are required to participate in the toolbox talk.

For example:
Say a toolbox talk is required to be carried out for all "female" employees who work in "warehousing".
I would then want my database in a datasheet subform on form - "Form: Toolbox Talk" to return all employees who are female and are marked as able to work in warehousing department.

I'll just add that I would like to avoid the intended system user using the filter buttons on the ribbon and my preference would be to use query's or vba if possible.

**What I have tried so far:**

**1.** I created a query ("Query: EmployeesperToolboxTalk") and added two tables ("Query: EmployeesExtended" & "Query: ToolboxTalksExtended"). I tried creating joins between the relevant fields (e.g. Gender to Gender, Department to Department etc.) but this did not work as either join properties 1, 2, or 3.
If I limit my join to say just departments, then that seems to do what I want but it doesn't include the other two variables which isn't really how I want it to work.

```
SELECT [Query: EmployeesExtended].[Employee Name], [Query: EmployeesExtended].Department, [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].[Toolbox Talk], [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].ToolTalkID, [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RecipientVariables
FROM [Query: EmployeesExtended] INNER JOIN [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended] ON ([Query: EmployeesExtended].Gender = [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RelatedGender) AND ([Query: EmployeesExtended].AdditionalCompetency.Value = [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RelatedCompetency.Value) AND ([Query: EmployeesExtended].Department.Value = [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RelatedDepartment.Value);
```

**2.** Following that, I created a union query to combine all the different variables into one:

```
SELECT [Table: Competencies].Competency
FROM [Table: Competencies];
UNION 
SELECT [Table: Departments].Department
FROM [Table: Departments];
UNION SELECT [Table: Gender].Gender
FROM [Table: Gender];
```

I then added a field "RecipientVariables" to table: "Table: Toolbox Talks" and set the row source to:

```
SELECT [Query: RecipientVariables].Competency
FROM [Query: RecipientVariables];
```

I then created a join from "RecipientVariables" to Departments, AdditionalCompetency and Gender:

```
SELECT [Query: EmployeesExtended].[Employee Name], [Query: EmployeesExtended].Department, [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].[Toolbox Talk], [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].ToolTalkID, [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RecipientVariables
FROM [Query: ToolboxTalksExtended] INNER JOIN [Query: EmployeesExtended] ON ([Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RecipientVariables.Value = [Query: EmployeesExtended].Department.Value) AND ([Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RecipientVariables.Value = [Query: EmployeesExtended].AdditionalCompetency.Value) AND ([Query: ToolboxTalksExtended].RecipientVariables.Value = [Query: EmployeesExtended].Gender);
```

This returns no results using join properties 1, 2 or 3.

**3.** The last thing I have tried is to create a second union query from my employees table ("Table: Employees"):

```
SELECT [Table: Employees].AdditionalCompetency.Value
FROM [Table: Employees];
UNION
SELECT [Table: Employees].Gender
FROM [Table: Employees];
UNION SELECT [Table: Employees].Department.Value
FROM [Table: Employees];
```

I then added a new field into my employee table: "AreasofCompetency" and set the Row Source as:
"Query: EmployeeVariables"

This also doesn't work.

I am now at a loss of what to try next.
Perhaps what I want to do is not possible or its much easier than I realise.

If someone can please give some guidance or perhaps offer an alternative suggestion, I would be very grateful. Please let me know if any additional info is required and I will gladly provide it.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: review database design and in particular table normalization.  The tables don't have to be user friendly that is what the forms and reports are for.

Comment: Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as per my comment first normalize your table structure.  For instance something like:

[image]

Then create a query that selects everything related to employees.  Here that is everything.  Select that query and click create form and access will make a form for you:
[image]
The unbound combobox and unbound listbox in the header are actually not there yet and the form shows every variable in the record source and hence is not user friendly.  add comboboxes and listboxes to the header for every variable you want to filter employees by.  Also delete and or move the labels and textboxes as you want.  Here I got:

[image]

Then you want to edit the after update event for the various unbound controls to filter the records.  for instance see [Filter form based on two combo box selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50355016/filter-form-based-on-two-combo-box-selections)

```
Private Sub cmbCompetency_AfterUpdate()
'cheap example hookup, same code for lstDepartments
Me.Filter = "EmployeesCompetencies.CompetencyID = " & cmbCompetency & " AND EmployeesDepartments.DepartmentID = " & cmbDepartment
Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

this gets you:
[image]

Comment: I might need you to fill in some blanks as I got thoroughly confused trying to do as per your suggestion. I created tables as per your example but I cant figure out how they interact. What I mean is that I have a form where I enter my employees (Form: Employee Profile) which is linked to Table: Employees. I can work out how to insert a combo box which has a row source of Table: Departments. What I cant figure out is how that info is then stored in the Table: EmployeesDepartments?? Combining them into a query as you suggested just returns a blank table.

Comment: most likely the data you entered into the table is malformed.  in a sense a query recombines several tables into one table.  but by default if any  columns in the new table would be blank the whole row is left blank.  Hence an empty table is the query result.  Look at this as a learning puzzle.  start with simple example tables, simple data, and simple queries and make sure what you get looks correct.  work up to the many to many relationship (hint) you have.

Comment: just in case, if the relationships between tables are not hooked up then you would also get a blank query.  In that case either add the relationships in each query or better do it once and for all under database tools-relationships.  (drag the primary key of one table to the corresponding foreign key in another table)

Comment: Hi Mazoula, Sorry it has taken me so long to get back to you. I did what you suggested and treated this as a learning puzzle. I started a new database with some very simple tables as per your example and I worked it out - thank you.

Comment: I then applied my learnings to my in development database and have had some success. My next issue is a situation where a field is blank. So every employee will be assigned a department, thats a given. However not everyone will necessarily be assigned a competency. When this is the case, these people don't show up in my query (Query: ToolboxTalk) and form (Form: ToolboxTalk). Is there any way for the query to show all employees even if they aren't assigned a competency? Do you have any other suggestion to get around this? I may have to create a default competency that everyone gets?

Comment: I haven't been able to get my head back into the question, but in general just wrap the variable that returns null in nz().  nz(variablewithnulls, replacementvalueifnull) combine with some if statements and control validation

Answer (score 0):

## Database Design

First you need to get rid of the multivalue columns. Using a multivalue columns never a good idea for several reasons and they are an especially bad idea when the same values appear in two or more tables and you want to join on those columns. Here is a normalized database design.

### Department table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Autonumber | Y | Primary key |
| Name | Short text | Y |  |

### Competency table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Autonumber | Y | Primary key |
| Name | Short text | Y |  |

### Employee table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Autonumber | Y | Primary key |
| First_Name | Short text | Y |  |
| Last_Name | Short text | Y |  |
| Gender | Short text | Y |  |

### Employee_Department table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Employee (Id) |
| Department_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Department (Id) |

### Employee_Competency table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Employee_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Employee (Id) |
| Competency_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Competency (Id) |

### Toolbox_Talk table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Id | Autonumber | Y | Primary key |
| Title | Short text | Y |  |
| Target_Gender | Short text | N | Null indicates no specific target gender (i.e., any value of gender) |

### Toolbox_Talk_Target_Department table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toolbox_Talk_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Toolbox_Talk (Id) |
| Department_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Department (Id) |

### Toolbox_Talk_Target_Competency table

| Column Name | Data type | Required | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Toolbox_Talk_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Toolbox_Talk (Id) |
| Competency_Id | int | Y | Foreign key references Competency (Id) |

## Query Design

Your query selection criteria are too complex to represent in SQL but you can use VBA to build your query in memory and then execute it like this.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sql As String
Dim whereClause As String

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly)
Do Until rs.EOF
    ' Process recordset
    rs.MoveNext
    DoEvents
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

The sql statement should select all employees who match the selection criteria for the talk. I assume you want each employee to appear only once, even if they match on several criteria. The sql statement looks like this.

```
sql = "Select E.Id, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name "
sql = sql & "From Employee E "
sql = sql & "Inner Join ("
sql = sql & "Select Distinct Id "
sql = sql & "From Employee "
sql = sql & whereClause
sql = sql & ") As Qry1 "
sql = sql & "On E.Id = Qry1.Id "
```

### Query Selection Criteria

Given a Toolbox_Talk_Id, you can get the target gender like this.

```
Dim targetGender As Variant

targetGender = DLookup("Target_Gender", "Toolbox_Talk", "Id = " & Toolbox_Talk_Id)
```

You can get the target departments like this.

```
Dim targetDepartments As Collection

Set targetDepartments = New Collection

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Select Department_Id From Toolbox_Talk_Target_Department Where Toolbox_Talk_Id = " & Toolbox_Talk_Id, dbOpenForwardOnly, dbReadOnly)
Do Until rs.EOF
    targetDepartments.Add rs!Department_Id.Value
    rs.MoveNext
    DoEvents
Loop
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

You can get the target competencies by querying the Toolbox_Talk_Target_Competency table the same way.

Given the target gender, departments, and competencies for the talk, you can now assemble the query's where clause.

If the talk target gender is not null, select only employees matching that gender.

```
If Not IsNull(targetGender) Then
    If Len(whereClause) = 0 Then
        whereClause = "WHERE "
    Else
        whereClause = whereClause & " AND "
    End If
    whereClause = whereClause & "Employee.Gender = " & Chr(34) & targetGender & Chr(34)
End If
```

If one or more target departments were specified, select only employees associated with those departments through the Employee_Department table.

```
If targetDepartments.Count > 0 Then
    If Len(whereClause) = 0 Then
        whereClause = "WHERE "
    Else
        whereClause = whereClause & " AND "
    End If
    If targetDepartments.Count = 1 Then
        ' one department
        whereClause = whereClause & "EXISTS (Select 1 From Employee_Department Where Employee_Id = Employee.Id And Department_Id = " & targetDepartments(1) & ") "
    Else
        ' two or more departments
        whereClause = whereClause & "EXISTS (Select 1 From Employee_Department Where Employee_Id = Employee.Id And Department_Id In (" & targetDepartments(1)
        For idx = 2 To targetDepartments.Count
            whereClause = whereClause & ", " & targetDepartments(idx)
        Next idx
        whereClause = whereClause & ")) "
    End If
End If
```

The end result should be a sql statement that looks something like this.

```
Select E.Id, E.First_Name, E.Last_Name 
From Employee E 
Inner Join (
Select Distinct Id 
From Employee 
Where Employee.Gender = "NB"
And EXISTS (Select 1 From Employee_Department Where Employee_Id = Employee.Id And Department_Id In (3, 4))
) As Qry1 
On E.Id = Qry1.Id
```